# Is it possible to create meeting scheduler for web application using google calendar?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to create one form using html and [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) that form contains some input controls, lets's assume input control Name, Venue, Start Time, End Time etc...

I want, the visitor of my website to fill that form and after submission, I want to see the created event in my Google Calendar account.

Comment: don't think there's Magic API for that. How bout your learn your client-side programming first?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to do this.  You should look into useing a [Service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  A service account is like a dummy user.   Share your calendar with the service account it will then have permissions to read and write to your person a calendar using the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).  Then create your form and using the service account insert into the calendar.

The users wont have to login they will just be able to add these events to the calendar.    I have an article that explains how service accounts work in detail that might help [Google developer beginners service accounts](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)

Comment: Hi @DalmTo thanks for you help, but still am struggling to display google calendar on UI side.

Comment: Which you UI side? Your webpage or Google calendar itself?  If you want to display google calendar on your webpage your going to have to code something yourself there is nothing out of the box for that.

Comment: I want, user to create event from web-page side and  to select when they are available or free for the event. Anyway, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You understand that Google calendar API isnt going to do any of that for you.  Its just going to let you insert data.   You will have to code this web page yourself.  good luck